# javax.validation.constraints to validate fraction number of digits of float variable

Tags: java, kotlin

I would like to validate a float number so that it would be in the format: `XXX.XX`. Which javax validation constraint could be used? Digits doesn't seem to support float data type

```
@field:NotNull
@field:Digits(fraction = 2, integer = 3)
var enrollmentPercentage: Float? = null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already noticed the `@BigDecimal` Annotation?
https://www.baeldung.com/javax-bigdecimal-validation
Also there's the posibility to use Annotations directly without `field:` as prefix. You may want to try this.